# Nested Query: Select results that are not in results of another query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-view

I have this sql query that finds the current status of an EquipmentItem by cross referencing the EquipmentItemReservations table:

```
SELECT EI.Id, ER.ReservationType AS Status 
FROM EquipmentItems AS EI 
  INNER JOIN EquipmentItemReservations AS ER ON EI.Id = ER.EquipmentItemId 
WHERE IsApproved = 1 
  AND DateShipped IS NOT NULL 
  AND DateReturned IS NULL
```

The reservations table has a ReservationType of either "Assigned" or "Allocated" which displays as "status" where applicable.

I would like to expand this query to get the EquipmentItems that did not meet the requirements, and set 'Available' AS Status for the rest of the items.

My goal is to have a full list of items with their status included ("Assigned", "Allocated", or "Available")

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with this query (made it an SQL view):

```
CREATE VIEW view_EquipmentItemStates AS 
    SELECT EI.Id, ER.ReservationType AS Status 
    FROM EquipmentItems AS EI LEFT JOIN EquipmentItemReservations AS ER 
    ON EI.Id = ER.EquipmentItemId 
    WHERE IsApproved = 1 AND DateShipped IS NOT NULL AND DateReturned IS NULL 
    UNION SELECT EquipmentItems.Id, 'Available' As Status 
    FROM EquipmentItems WHERE EquipmentItems.Id NOT IN (
        SELECT EI.Id FROM EquipmentItems AS EI LEFT JOIN EquipmentItemReservations AS ER 
        ON EI.Id = ER.EquipmentItemIdWHERE IsApproved = 1 AND DateShipped IS NOT NULL 
        AND DateReturned IS NULL)
```